# Flutter: How to create a widget class that is transparent?

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to create a new widget class with a container size of 250x500 with the rest of the class/widget  0.5 opacity - allowing the prior widget - we launched from - to be partially visible.

Is this possible ? if so how ?

-Thanks

Below is the Stateful class I am calling

```
class ShowMyTitles extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ShowMyTitlesState createState() => _ShowMyTitlesState();
}

class _ShowMyTitlesState extends State<ShowMyTitles> {


  List<Map<String, bool>> myListOfMapTitles;
  Map<String, bool> valuesHeaders;
  int trueCount = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    SettingsForMap SFM = new SettingsForMap();
    myListOfMapTitles = SFM.myListOfMapTitles;
    valuesHeaders = SFM.valuesHeaders;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List myTitles = [];

    return new WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: (){
        myListOfMapTitles.forEach((valuesAll) {
          valuesAll.forEach((s,b){
            if(b == true) {
              myTitles.add(s);
              print('My Selecteed titles are = ' + s.toString());
            }
          });

        });
        Navigator.pop(context, myTitles);

      },
      child: new Container(
        child: new GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){
            myListOfMapTitles.forEach((valuesAll) {
              valuesAll.forEach((s,b){
                if(b == true) {
                  myTitles.add(s);
                  print('My Selecteed titles are = ' + s.toString());
                }
              });

            });
            Navigator.pop(context, myTitles);
          },
          child: _titlesDialog(context, 'Select 2 Titles (Max)'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 15):

There is an [`Opacity`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html) widget. Wrap the widget you want to be transparent within it.

`Opacity(child:MyTransparentWidget(),opacity:0.45)`

Comment: thanks for the help but the opacity seems to sit on top of the MyTransparentWidget().  If you set the  opacity to 0.1 on your example you can no longer see the widget.

Comment: I do not understand what is the problem here

Answer (score 2):

You can use Stack widget for that.

Surround the `widget which you want to change the opacity` and the `container` with **`Stack`** widget.

Then wrap the `widget which you want to change the opacity` with **`Opacity`** widget and mention required opacity.

Make sure you put the container after the `widget which you want to change the opacity` then only it will sit above the transparent widget

Answer (score 0):

To make any widget transparent, you make that widget a child of a parent Theme() widget. e.g

```
class TransparentWidget extends StatelessWidget {

 @override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
       // Set the transparency here
       canvasColor: Colors.white70, //or any other color you want. e.g Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5)
      ),
      child: Container(
          height: 250.0,
          width: 250.0,
          child: Text("Hello World")
       )
    );
  }
}
```

OR

Simply make the main container background decoration an opaque color.

```
 Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
     )
 );
```